# how to submit the form after validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, bootstrap-4

I have a beautiful form that has a great validation with jQuery, but where do I put the function that should run after fom was validated?

here is the form:

```
<form id="myForm" class=" needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="rendered-form">
       
        <div class="form-group row formbuilder-text form-group field-text-1650256863373">
            <label for="text-1650256863373" class="col-sm-2 formbuilder-text-label">Name<span class="formbuilder-required">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text-1650256863373" access="false" maxlength="50" id="text-1650256863373" required="required" aria-required="true">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row formbuilder-text form-group field-text-1650256864829">
            <label for="text-1650256864829" class="col-sm-2 formbuilder-text-label">E-mail:<span class="formbuilder-required">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="text-1650256864829" access="false" maxlength="30" id="text-1650256864829" required="required" aria-required="true">
                <div class="invalid-feedback">e-mail</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row formbuilder-text form-group field-text-1650256865677">
            <label for="text-1650256865677" class="col-sm-2 formbuilder-text-label">Phone<span class="formbuilder-required">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <div class="input-group-text">+1</div>

                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="text-1650256865677" access="false" maxlength="15" id="text-1650256865677" required="required" aria-required="true">
                </div>
               
            </div>
            </div>
        
                <div class="formbuilder-button form-group field-button-1650256992197">
                    <button type="submit"  class="btn-success btn" name="button-1650256992197" access="false" style="success" id="button-1650256992197">Подписать</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    
</form>
```

here is my javascript validation:

```
  <script>
    // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
    (() => {
        'use strict';

    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation');

    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach((form) => {
        form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    form.classList.add('was-validated');
    }, false);
    });
    })();


</script>
```

Now when user clicks one the button Submit, if the form is validated I need to show an alert window with message. Where I put it?

Comment: The form validation works fine, and it is submitted if all inputs check out. Not sure what you're asking. If you want to run ajax code or whatever if the form checks out, add an `else` block after the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `checkValidity()` is a boolean function.

```html
<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(() => {
    'use strict';
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach((form) => {
        form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
            if(!form.checkValidity()) {
                // When is invalid
                alert('invalid');
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            } else {
                // When is valid
                alert('valid');
            }
            // On form submit whether valid or invalid
            alert('Was validated');
            form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
    });
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could just try to add the alert that you want at the end of your script ? It gonna be display if you script go at the end of it logic !

```
 <script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are     invalid fields
(() => {
    'use strict';

// Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation  styles to
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation');

// Loop over them and prevent submission
Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach((form) => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    if (!form.checkValidity()) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}
form.classList.add('was-validated');
}, false);
});
alert('What you want to say to user');
})();


</script>
```

I guess you can put it where you want, but after your logic to see if it's run fully and correctly.

Comment: That will display the alert when the script runs. It's not even completely clear what OP is looking for. Also, please indent code when you post answers. And don't post answers to questions that seem easy and obvious, because those aren't supposed to be posted here in the first place.